# What is the integral of $(\ln(4-2x))^2$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \ln^2(4-2x)\ dx$$

I have tried many ways to do this, but I have yet to come to an answer.

Comment: Alternatively, Let $4-2x = e^u$ and $-2dx = e^udu$ to get
$$\frac{-1}{2}\int u^2 e^u du$$

Comment: This is interesting. That is a creative way of doing it. I appreciate it!

Comment: @KingTut yep that's how I would do it but people are so awfully fast at this site.

Comment: I prefer this website over my professors. It takes no more than two minutes to receive help from someone. This seems counterintuitive to me. I have had 2 weeks exposure to calculus in highschool, but I studied hard and passed the AP calc ab exam. I am now a freshman in college, and I am in calc 2. My overall experience with creatively solving integrals and other calculus related problems is slim compared to you all.  @mathreadler

Comment: @Michael : Yes, professors often have responsibilities which students don't see so much in everyday life. It takes time to prepare lectures, correct hand ins, do research, present research, apply for grants. Or if they are older students they have their own exams to study for. On here it could basically be any hobo mathfreak with lots of spare time. ;)

Comment: I meant no offense towards professors at all in that comment. I would love to clear that up. I reread it and it seemed as though I was neglecting the being of professors. They have responsibilities, and I respect that. This website, just as you stated, is great for asking questions that I have when my professor is at home committing to his.her studies and/or family. I love the people on stack exchange and all of my professors for the help they all provide, including you! @mathreadler

Comment: Try not to worry. Just work hard and be nice. Most professors know that many students don't know about all the stuff their job includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make the substitution $u = 4 - 2x$. This is just a linear change of variables.

Now use the formula $$\int \ln^2 x dx = x \bigg(\ln^2 x - 2 \ln x +2 \bigg) +C $$

This formula can be obtained by integration by parts with $u = \ln^2 x$ and $dv = dx$, if I recall correctly.

Comment: I see what you did. Thank you so much! I should have followed through after ln^2(u). @alfred yerger

Answer (score 1):

First, start with a simple u-substitution; it is a linear term so after the change of variables it will not complicate the integral: $u=4-2x$

$$\int \ln^2 u\:\mathrm{d}u(-\frac{1}{2})=-\frac{1}{2}\int \ln^2u \: \mathrm{d}u$$

Then, integrate by parts($\int u\:\mathrm{d}v=uv-\int v\:\mathrm{d}u$); it is easy to define the easy to derivate one as the $u$ function, or the easy to integrate as the $\mathrm{d}v$. Since it is easy for us to derivate $\ln^2\: x$.

Then, $\int \ln^2 x\: \mathrm{d}x$, with $u=\ln^2 x\:\:\:\mathrm{d}u=2(\ln\:x)(\ln\:x)'=\frac{2\ln\:x}{x}\ln\:\:\:\:v=x\:\:\:\:\mathrm{d}v=1$:

$$\int \ln^2 x\: dx = x\ln^2x-\int2\ln\:x\: \mathrm{d}x$$

And by parts again,$u=\ln\:x\:\:\:\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{x}\ln\:\:\:\:v=x\:\:\:\:\mathrm{d}v=1$

$$x\ln^2x-\int2\ln\:x\: \mathrm{d}x = x\ln^2x-2\int \ln\:x\:\mathrm{d}x$$

$$x\ln^2x-\int2\ln\:x\: \mathrm{d}x = x\ln^2x-2(x\ln\:x-\int x\:\frac{1}{x}\mathrm{d}x) $$

$$x\ln^2x-\int2\ln\:x\: \mathrm{d}x = x\ln^2x-2(x\ln\:x-\int \mathrm{d}x) $$

$$x\ln^2x-\int2\ln\:x\: \mathrm{d}x = x\ln^2x-2(x\ln\:x-x+C) $$

Putting into the integral above,

$$-\frac{1}{2}\int \ln^2u \:\mathrm{d}u=  -\frac{1}{2}\left [u\ln^2u-2(u\ln\:u-u+C) \right ]$$

Substitute back the $u$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $u = 2x - 4 \longrightarrow \text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\text{d}u$
$$\int\ln^2({4 - 2x})~\text{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\int(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2~\text{d}u\tag{1}$$
Lets solve the inner part of the integral in $(1)$. Substitute $v = \ln(u) \longrightarrow \text{d}u = u\text{d}v$
$$\int(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2~\text{d}u = \int(v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}u\tag{2}$$
Integrate by parts to get $$\int(v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}u = (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v - 2\int (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}v\tag{3}$$
Lets solve the inner part of the integral in $(2)$. Integrate by parts to get
$$\int (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}v = (v + \ln(-1))e^v - \int e^v~\text{d}v = (v + \ln(-1))e^v - e^v\tag{4}$$
Plug in $(4)$ in $(3)$, $$ \begin{align*}(v + \ln(-1))^2e^v - 2\int (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}v &= (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v - 2((v + \ln(-1))e^v - e^v)\\ &= (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v - 2(v + \ln(-1))e^v) + 2e^v\tag{5} \end{align*}$$
Reverse substitution in $(5)$,
$$(v + \ln(-1))^2e^v - 2\int (v + \ln(-1))^2e^v~\text{d}v = u(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2 - 2u(\ln(u) + \ln(-1)) + 2u\tag{6}$$
Comparing $(3)$ and $(6)$,$$ \int(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2~\text{d}u = u(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2 - 2u(\ln(u) + \ln(-1)) + 2u\tag{7}$$
Plug in $(7)$ in (1), $$\frac{1}{2}\int(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2~\text{d}u = \frac{u(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2}{2} - u\ln(u) + \ln(-1) + u\tag{8}$$
Reverse substitution in $(8)$, $$\begin{align*}\frac{1}{2}&\int(\ln(u) + \ln(-1))^2~\text{d}u = \\&\frac{(2x - 4)(\ln(2x - 4) + \ln(-1))^2}{2} - (2x - 4)(\ln(2x - 4) + \ln(-1)) + 2x - 4\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}\implies&\int\ln^2({4 - 2x})~\text{d}x = \\&\frac{(2x - 4)(\ln(2x - 4) + \ln(-1))^2}{2} - (2x - 4)(\ln(2x - 4) + \ln(-1)) + 2x - 4 + C\end{align*}$$